# getting outputs in simulation as all high impedance. topic: restoring algorithm for binary division

Tags: verilog, high-impedance, testbench

I am getting outputs of my hardware as all high impedance (ZZZZZ). i tried synthesizing the code and got these warnings. I think there might be a problem in the test bench i am trying to run.

```
    source div_restoring.tcl -notrace
Command: synth_design -top div_restoring -part xc7z010clg400-3
Starting synth_design
Attempting to get a license for feature 'Synthesis' and/or device 'xc7z010'
INFO: [Common 17-349] Got license for feature 'Synthesis' and/or device 'xc7z010'
INFO: Launching helper process for spawning children vivado processes
INFO: Helper process launched with PID 8248 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting Synthesize : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:02 ; elapsed = 00:00:02 . Memory (MB): peak = 357.441 ; gain = 99.344
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: [Synth 8-6157] synthesizing module 'div_restoring' [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:24]
WARNING: [Synth 8-5788] Register reg_q_reg in module div_restoring is has both Set and reset with same priority. This may cause simulation mismatches. Consider rewriting code  [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:38]
WARNING: [Synth 8-5788] Register reg_b_reg in module div_restoring is has both Set and reset with same priority. This may cause simulation mismatches. Consider rewriting code  [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:38]
WARNING: [Synth 8-5788] Register reg_r_reg in module div_restoring is has both Set and reset with same priority. This may cause simulation mismatches. Consider rewriting code  [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:38]
WARNING: [Synth 8-5788] Register count_reg in module div_restoring is has both Set and reset with same priority. This may cause simulation mismatches. Consider rewriting code  [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:60]
INFO: [Synth 8-6155] done synthesizing module 'div_restoring' (1#1) [C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.srcs/sources_1/new/div_restoring.v:24]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Synthesize : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:03 ; elapsed = 00:00:03 . Memory (MB): peak = 411.883 ; gain = 153.785
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Constraint Validation : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:03 ; elapsed = 00:00:04 . Memory (MB): peak = 411.883 ; gain = 153.785
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Loading Part and Timing Information
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Loading part: xc7z010clg400-3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Loading Part and Timing Information : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:03 ; elapsed = 00:00:04 . Memory (MB): peak = 411.883 ; gain = 153.785
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: [Device 21-403] Loading part xc7z010clg400-3
INFO: [Synth 8-5546] ROM "busy" won't be mapped to RAM because it is too sparse
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished RTL Optimization Phase 2 : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:03 ; elapsed = 00:00:04 . Memory (MB): peak = 411.883 ; gain = 153.785
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report RTL Partitions: 
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
| |RTL Partition |Replication |Instances |
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
No constraint files found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start RTL Component Statistics 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Detailed RTL Component Info : 
+---Adders : 
       3 Input     17 Bit       Adders := 1     
       2 Input      5 Bit       Adders := 1     
+---Registers : 
                   32 Bit    Registers := 1     
                   16 Bit    Registers := 2     
                    5 Bit    Registers := 1     
                    1 Bit    Registers := 2     
+---Muxes : 
       2 Input     32 Bit        Muxes := 1     
       2 Input     16 Bit        Muxes := 2     
       2 Input      5 Bit        Muxes := 1     
       2 Input      1 Bit        Muxes := 3     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished RTL Component Statistics 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start RTL Hierarchical Component Statistics 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hierarchical RTL Component report 
Module div_restoring 
Detailed RTL Component Info : 
+---Adders : 
       3 Input     17 Bit       Adders := 1     
       2 Input      5 Bit       Adders := 1     
+---Registers : 
                   32 Bit    Registers := 1     
                   16 Bit    Registers := 2     
                    5 Bit    Registers := 1     
                    1 Bit    Registers := 2     
+---Muxes : 
       2 Input     32 Bit        Muxes := 1     
       2 Input     16 Bit        Muxes := 2     
       2 Input      5 Bit        Muxes := 1     
       2 Input      1 Bit        Muxes := 3     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished RTL Hierarchical Component Statistics
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Part Resource Summary
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Part Resources:
DSPs: 80 (col length:40)
BRAMs: 120 (col length: RAMB18 40 RAMB36 20)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Part Resource Summary
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No constraint files found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Cross Boundary and Area Optimization
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: Parallel synthesis criteria is not met 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Cross Boundary and Area Optimization : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:08 ; elapsed = 00:00:11 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report RTL Partitions: 
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
| |RTL Partition |Replication |Instances |
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
No constraint files found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Timing Optimization
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Timing Optimization : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:08 ; elapsed = 00:00:11 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report RTL Partitions: 
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
| |RTL Partition |Replication |Instances |
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Technology Mapping
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Technology Mapping : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:08 ; elapsed = 00:00:11 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report RTL Partitions: 
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
| |RTL Partition |Replication |Instances |
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start IO Insertion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Flattening Before IO Insertion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Flattening Before IO Insertion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Final Netlist Cleanup
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Final Netlist Cleanup
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished IO Insertion : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report Check Netlist: 
+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------------------+
|      |Item              |Errors |Warnings |Status |Description       |
+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------------------+
|1     |multi_driven_nets |      0|        0|Passed |Multi driven nets |
+------+------------------+-------+---------+-------+------------------+
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Renaming Generated Instances
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Renaming Generated Instances : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report RTL Partitions: 
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
| |RTL Partition |Replication |Instances |
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
+-+--------------+------------+----------+
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Rebuilding User Hierarchy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Rebuilding User Hierarchy : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Renaming Generated Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Renaming Generated Ports : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Handling Custom Attributes
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Handling Custom Attributes : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Renaming Generated Nets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Renaming Generated Nets : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Start Writing Synthesis Report
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report BlackBoxes: 
+-+--------------+----------+
| |BlackBox name |Instances |
+-+--------------+----------+
+-+--------------+----------+

Report Cell Usage: 
+------+-------+------+
|      |Cell   |Count |
+------+-------+------+
|1     |BUFG   |     1|
|2     |CARRY4 |     5|
|3     |LUT1   |     3|
|4     |LUT2   |    20|
|5     |LUT3   |    51|
|6     |LUT4   |     1|
|7     |LUT5   |     2|
|8     |FDCE   |     2|
|9     |FDRE   |    69|
|10    |IBUF   |    51|
|11    |OBUF   |    55|
+------+-------+------+

Report Instance Areas: 
+------+---------+-------+------+
|      |Instance |Module |Cells |
+------+---------+-------+------+
|1     |top      |       |   260|
+------+---------+-------+------+
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Writing Synthesis Report : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Synthesis finished with 0 errors, 0 critical warnings and 4 warnings.
Synthesis Optimization Runtime : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
Synthesis Optimization Complete : Time (s): cpu = 00:00:10 ; elapsed = 00:00:13 . Memory (MB): peak = 551.531 ; gain = 293.434
INFO: [Project 1-571] Translating synthesized netlist
INFO: [Netlist 29-17] Analyzing 56 Unisim elements for replacement
INFO: [Netlist 29-28] Unisim Transformation completed in 0 CPU seconds
INFO: [Project 1-570] Preparing netlist for logic optimization
INFO: [Opt 31-138] Pushed 0 inverter(s) to 0 load pin(s).
INFO: [Project 1-111] Unisim Transformation Summary:
No Unisim elements were transformed.

INFO: [Common 17-83] Releasing license: Synthesis
12 Infos, 4 Warnings, 0 Critical Warnings and 0 Errors encountered.
synth_design completed successfully
synth_design: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:15 ; elapsed = 00:00:18 . Memory (MB): peak = 655.586 ; gain = 410.492
WARNING: [Constraints 18-5210] No constraint will be written out.
INFO: [Common 17-1381] The checkpoint 'C:/Users/ERis/LAB_THREE/LAB_THREE.runs/synth_3/div_restoring.dcp' has been generated.
INFO: [runtcl-4] Executing : report_utilization -file div_restoring_utilization_synth.rpt -pb div_restoring_utilization_synth.pb
report_utilization: Time (s): cpu = 00:00:00 ; elapsed = 00:00:00.100 . Memory (MB): peak = 655.586 ; gain = 0.000
INFO: [Common 17-206] Exiting Vivado at Mon Jul  2 21:47:59 2018...
```

source code is

```
    `timescale 1ns / 1ps
module div_restoring (a,b,start,clk,clrn,q,r,busy,ready,count);
    input [31:0] a; // dividend
    input [15:0] b; // divisor
    input start; // start
    input clk, clrn; // clk,reset
    output [31:0] q; // quotient
    output [15:0] r; // remainder
    output reg busy; // busy
    output reg ready; // ready
    output [4:0] count; // counter
    reg [31:0] reg_q;   // reg_q 32 bit
    reg [15:0] reg_r;   // reg_r 16 bit
    reg [15:0] reg_b;   // reg_b 16 bit
    reg [4:0] count;
    wire [16:0] sub_out = {reg_r,reg_q[31]} - {1'b0,reg_b}; // concatination and substraction
    wire [15:0] mux_out = sub_out[16]? // restoring
            {reg_r[14:0],reg_q[31]} : sub_out[15:0]; // or not

    assign q = reg_q;
    assign r = reg_r;
    always @ (posedge clk or negedge clrn) 
    begin
        if (!clrn) 
        begin
            busy <= 0;
            ready <= 0;
        end 
        else 
        begin
            if (start) 
            begin
                reg_q <= a; // load a
                reg_b <= b; // load b
                reg_r <= 0;
                busy <= 1;
                ready <= 0;
                count <= 0;
            end 
            else if (busy) 
            begin
                reg_q <= {reg_q[30:0],sub_out[16]}; // << 1
                reg_r <= mux_out;
                count <= count + 5'b1; // counter++
                if (count == 5'h1f) 
                begin // finished
                    busy <= 0;
                    ready <= 1; // q,r ready
                end
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

the test bench i am using is

```
    module test_tb;
    reg [31:0] a;
    reg [15:0] b;
    reg start,clk_200,clrn;
    wire [31:0] q;
    wire [15:0] r;
    wire busy,ready;
    wire [4:0] count;

    // instantiate device under test
    div_restoring dut(
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .start(start),
    .clk(clk_200),
    .clrn(clrn)
    ); 

    // generate 200 mhz clock

    initial
    begin
        clk_200 = 1;
        start = 0;
        clrn = 0;
        assign a = 32'H0;
        assign b = 16'H0;



        #5 start = 1;
        clrn = 1;
        assign a = 32'H4c7f228a;
        assign b = 16'H6a0e;
        #10 start = 0;
    end
    always
            #5 clk_200 = ~clk_200; 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testbench isn't connecting any signals to the DUT outputs (q, r, busy, ready, count). You declared the signals in the testbench but didn't make the connections.

> how would i do that ? everywhere i search for a testbench example i do not see 'the connection' you are talking about.

You do it the exact same way you connected the inputs:

```
 // instantiate device under test
    div_restoring dut(
    // inputs:
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .start(start),
    .clk(clk_200),
    .clrn(clrn),
    // Outputs:
    .q(q),              
    .r(r), 
    // etc.
    );
```

Comment: how should i do that ? doesn't the instance of source code in test bench generate the output ? i am totally lost here..

Comment: oh i can use $monitor(); i think. i'll try to do it and see if it works right.

Comment: initial
        begin
            $monitor(q,r,busy,ready,count);
        end  // i used this block and i am still getting zzzzz as all outputs

Comment: Your module has 10 inputs and outputs. When you instantiate it in your testbench you only connect testbench-level signals to 5 of the module's inputs and outputs. If you monitor the signal `q` in the testbench, without connecting it to the signal `q` in the module it will have a `z` value because nothing is driving it.

Comment: @ThePhoton how would i do that ? everywhere i search for a testbench example i do not see 'the connection' you are talking about. i only see that the source module is used and inputs are declared as registers and outputs as wires. thats it.

Comment: @ErisDrater, where you have `div_restoring dut(...)` in the testbench you have to include `.q(q)`, `.r(r)`, etc.,  the exact same way you did for the module inputs.